# Does InterpolationOrder cause conflicts with PlotMarkers in ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0 or later**

---

My code:

```
data = {MapIndexed[{First[#2], #1} &, 
    Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {54}]]], 
   MapIndexed[{First[#2], #1} &, 
    Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {34}]]]};

ListPlot[data,
 Axes -> False,
 AspectRatio -> 0.75,
 Frame -> True,
 InterpolationOrder -> {0, 0},
 ImageSize -> {400, 300},
 ImageMargins -> 0,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledCircle]", 11}, {"", 11}}
 ]
```

On OS X 10.6.8 V8.0.4 I get this output:

[image]

You will note that the filled circle plot markers have been "distributed" across both sets of data. However if I change the `InterpolationOrder` setting to say:

```
InterpolationOrder -> {0, None}
```

...then no markers appear for the second set of data (due to the markers being an empty string).

[image]

Could someone please advise me if the cause of this behaviour is due to me setting these options incorrectly? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I see this too. To see if it's related to the shape of the lists, I tried the following, but got the same wrong plot with `InterpolationOrder -> {0, 0}` (and it's also wrong with `ListLinePlot`): `data = {Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {54}]], 
   Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {34}]]};`

Comment: Interesting. If I try `InterpolationOrder -> 0`, both plots are marked, while with `InterpolationOrder -> 1`, only one set is marked. Hmm...

Comment: Further intriguing behavior: `ListPlot[data, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.75, Frame -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledCircle]", 11}, {"\[FilledSmallSquare]", 11}}]`. (Setting `InterpolationOrder -> 1` gives the expected result, however.)

Comment: @ilian, I presume somebody *there* is looking at this now? This has lasted quite a while…

Comment: @J. M. I've notified the developers/QA listed on the internal bug report.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotMarkers.html), the second result is correct, since $i$-th specification in `PlotMakers` should be used for $i$-th dataset. There seems to be a bug regarding how `InterpolationOrder->0` is processing `PlotMarkers`.

When `InterpolationOrder->0`, it inserts `PlotMarkers` at the both end of each interval. Not so for all other cases (it inserts markers on the data point). While doing so, it seems that it always picks up the first plot marker for the end interval point, instead of the correct one (n-th plot maker for n-th data set).

It is easy to confirm. Define multi-data:

```
SeedRandom[2]; data = {MapIndexed[{First[#2], #1} &, 
   Accumulate[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10}]]], 
  MapIndexed[{First[#2], #1} &, 
   Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {15}]]],
  MapIndexed[{First[#2], #1} &, 
   Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-1, 0}, {15}]]]};
```

Then run the plot with interpolation order 0:

```
ListPlot[data, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.75, Frame -> True, 
 InterpolationOrder -> {0, 0, 0}, ImageSize -> {400, 300}, 
 ImageMargins -> 0, Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledCircle]", 8}, {"\[FilledSquare]", 
    10}, {"\[FilledDiamond]", 10}}]
```

The result is:

[image]

When it should have looked like this:

[image]

(which is generated by:

```
Show[MapThread[
  ListPlot[#1, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.75, Frame -> True, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 0, ImageSize -> {400, 300}, 
    ImageMargins -> 0, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> #2, 
    PlotStyle -> #3] &, {data, {{"\[FilledCircle]", 
     8}, {"\[FilledSquare]", 10}, {"\[FilledDiamond]", 10}}, 
   ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[1 ;; 3]]}], PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, All}]
```

)

Comment: Will you log it as a bug?

Comment: Already did, Mike.

Comment: Three years later and the bug remains.  Would someone agitate the water a bit, please?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, considering that Yu-Sung isn't "there" anymore, we should prolly be bugging somebody else…

Comment: @J. M. Sorry, my memory is terrible.