# PlotMarkers don't change colour for different lines

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0**

---

I have a set of data and several function operating on the same data, that I wish to plot together in a `ListPlot`. I need different `PlotMarkers` for each function to visualise the data. Because the data is quite closely spaced, I specified the number of markers using `Mesh` in the way I found here: [Custom Intervals of Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789047/custom-intervals-of-markers-in-mathematica-plotmarkers)

So I have the following:

```
a = Table[ii, {ii, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.01}];
b = Sin[a];
c = Sin[a + \[Pi]/4 ];

ListPlot[
  {Transpose[{a, b}],
   Transpose[{a, c}]
  },
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 Joined -> True,
 Mesh -> 20]
```

However, the `Mesh` command suddenly makes all markers the same shape and colour, so this is what I get out:

[image]

How can I make sure that the `PlotMarkers`' colour and shape remain unchanged while being able to specify the number of markers in the plot?

I'm using Mathematica 9.

Comment: Possibly related: [(7201)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7201/121)

Comment: The given code does not yield the given plot under my Mma 9. Are you sure this is what you are entering? For starters, why would a `ListPlot` join the dots ... unless told to do so? Orrrr ... are you actually using `ListLinePlot` rather than `ListPlot`?

Comment: You are right, it was exactly what I entered, but I'd forgotten that I'd added a `SetOptions[ListPlot, Joined -> True];` earlier in the Notebook, sorry for that. It also seems like that is exactly what makes the difference. Without the `Joined->True` it works, with it, the markers change. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: You're mixing plot points and mesh points. What you are seeing is the mesh points, but if you happen to choose the number of mesh points correctly where they _are_ plot points, then you get the behavior you're seeing. And, yes, it is a bug, and already reported.

Comment: I don't completely understand: how exactly do you suggest to choose the Mesh points correctly? And can it be done when you assume that the data (in this case `a`) is randomly sampled, rather than evenly distributed like in this example?

Comment: If your points are equally spaced, then it shouldn't be to difficult to come up with a number where they coincide. But, as they are not, you can't. Mostly, my prior comment was just an FYI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the version of `Mesh` where you specify an explicit list of coordinates, taking these directly from `a`:

```
Module[{meshpoints = 20},
 With[{step = Round[Length[a]/(meshpoints + 1)]}, 
  ListPlot[{Transpose[{a, b}], Transpose[{a, c}]}, 
   PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> True, 
   Mesh -> {a[[step ;; -step ;; step]]}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. It's interesting that this circumvents the bug, but `Mesh -> {Table[i, {i, 0, 2 Pi, .2}]}` does not.

Comment: @MichaelE2, it looks like a rounding error thing - if you use `1/100` and `1/5` instead of `0.01` and `0.2` the bug goes away.

Comment: So the mesh coordinates have to be (some of) the first coordinates of the of the second list, I guess.  (Oops, for some reason I had used `SameQ` instead of just subtracting `a[[;; -1 ;; Round[0.2/0.01]]] - Table[i, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}]`.)

Comment: This is a beautiful way of working around the bug indeed: it even works for non-equally spaced data, and still keeps the option to add anything else you may want to add to `ListPlot` (like a legend). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a bug, though I cannot pinpoint it.  I suggest you plot the lines separately and combine with `Show`, e.g.:

```
Show[
 MapIndexed[
  ListLinePlot[#, PlotMarkers -> Graphics`PlotMarkers[][[#2]], 
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[#2]], Mesh -> 20] &,
  {Transpose[{a, b}], Transpose[{a, c}]}
 ],
 PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image]

`PlotRange -> All` is included for the case where the first plot doesn't cover the full range of the second plot; without there would be truncation.

Comment: It does look like a bug indeed. This is a good suggestion, although I didn't mention I have to add a Legend too. That's a deal harder with combined plots in `Show`...

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat awkward way to get points onto your `ListLinePlot` would be to use `Epilog`

```
a = Table[ii, {ii, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.01}];
b = Sin[a];
c = Sin[a + \[Pi]/4];

ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{a, b}], Transpose[{a, c}]}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Blue, 
   Point@Take[Transpose[{a, b}], {1, -1, 20}], Red, 
   Point@Take[Transpose[{a, c}], {1, -1, 20}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{Blue, Red}, {"one", "two"}]]
```

This addresses your desire to have one plot command without using `Show` and provides a mechanism for including a legend.  I'll leave it to others to come up with more elegant solutions.