# ListLogLinearPlot with customize Mesh mix up the markers in multiple curve

Tags: plotting

I have to plot several curves in logarithmic scale. I used `ListLogLinearPlot` and customized the Mesh option. Then the markers mixed up.

```
x = Range[0, 5, 0.1];
ListLogLinearPlot[{Transpose[{x, Sin[x]}], Transpose[{x, Cos[x]}]}, 
    PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> True, 
    Mesh -> {x[[{2, 3, 4, 6, 11, 21, 31}]]}]
```

[image: The markers mixed up]
And I try not to use the logarithmic plot but `ListPlot`. It's OK.

```
ListPlot[{Transpose[{x, Sin[x]}], Transpose[{x, Cos[x]}]}, 
    PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> True, 
    Mesh -> {x[[{2, 3, 4, 6, 11, 21, 31}]]}]
```

[image: The markers are correct]

I have learned the Mesh bug in [PlotMarkers don't change colour for different lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28267/plotmarkers-dont-change-colour-for-different-lines). However, the logarithmic plot has a more sophisticated problem. I am using Mathematica 9.
Thanks!

Comment: This probably *is* a bug but by convention we do not start with that tag applied.  Also I removed `Graphics` as this appear to be only an issue with a plotting function an not the underlying `Graphics` system.

Comment: Similar appearing but apparently different bug: [(41706)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41706/121)

Comment: The [answer given in your linked question by Mr.Wizard](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28269/18476) seems to be a proper workaround for this case too, isn't it?

Comment: @Karsten7 That is a fairly general way to approach such problems but it is also good to have Q&A's to report/track these bugs, IMO.  This one affects version 7 as well so it appears to be another longstanding PlotMarkers bug like [(7201)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7201/121) and 41706.

Comment: Does not happen on v10

Comment: I tried with v10.1, the problem lasts. @yohbs

Comment: @robit weird. I'm using 10.0 on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm using v10.1 on win7. @yohbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, this does not happen on my computer (v10.0 on Ubuntu). But you can easily circumvent this problem by a number of ways. here's one:

```
x = Range[0, 5, 0.1];
ptsToPlot = {2, 3, 4, 6, 11, 21, 31};
g1 = ListLogLinearPlot[{
    Transpose[{x, Sin[x]}],
    Transpose[{x, Cos[x]}]
    }, Joined -> True];
g2 = ListLogLinearPlot[{
    Transpose[{x, Sin[x]}][[ptsToPlot]],
    Transpose[{x, Cos[x]}][[ptsToPlot]]
    }, PlotMarkers -> Automatic];
Show[g1, g2]
```

[image]

Comment: I have to use this method now, though i hope Mathematica fix that bug. Thank you!

Comment: But there's something more sophisticated with the log scale plotting. Such as the ticks' problem. So I now turn to matplotlib  as an front end.  : ( @yohbs